# How to repeat program after user inputs a choice

Tags: python

I am trying to create a text-based purchasing system as an assignment for school. I need help making it so users can "purchase in bulk" meaning after the user chooses a doughnut(one of the menu choices), it would bring back the choices or tell the user to say a keyword and stops.

Here is an example of how it should go:

```
Welcome, to Dino's International Doughnut Shoppe!           
    Please enter your name to begin: Andrew

    Please select a doughnut from the following menu:
    1. Chocolate-dipped Maple Puff ($3.50 each)
    2. Strawberry Twizzler ($2.25 each)
    3. Vanilla Chai Strudel ($4.05 each)
    4. Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie ($1.99)
    5. No more doughnuts.
    > 7
    I'm sorry, that's not a valid selection. Please enter a selection from 1-5.

    Please select a doughnut from the following menu:
    1. Chocolate-dipped Maple Puff ($3.50 each)
    2. Strawberry Twizzler ($2.25 each)
    3. Vanilla Chai Strudel ($4.05 each)
    4. Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie ($1.99)
    5. No more doughnuts.
    > 1

    How many Chocolate-dipped Maple Puffs would you like to purchase? 12

    Please select a doughnut from the following menu:
    1. Chocolate-dipped Maple Puff ($3.50 each)
    2. Strawberry Twizzler ($2.25 each)
    3. Vanilla Chai Strudel ($4.05 each)
    4. Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie ($1.99)
    5. No more doughnuts.
    > 4

    How many Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchies would you like to purchase? 8

    Please select a doughnut from the following menu:
    1. Chocolate-dipped Maple Puff ($3.50 each)
    2. Strawberry Twizzler ($2.25 each)
    3. Vanilla Chai Strudel ($4.05 each)
    4. Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie ($1.99)
    5. No more doughnuts.
    > 4

    How many Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchies would you like to purchase? 3

    Please select a doughnut from the following menu:
    1. Chocolate-dipped Maple Puff ($3.50 each)
    2. Strawberry Twizzler ($2.25 each)
    3. Vanilla Chai Strudel ($4.05 each)
    4. Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie ($1.99)
    5. No more doughnuts.
    > 5

    Andrew, here is your receipt:
    -------------------------------------
    12 Chocolate-dipped Maple Puffs
    3 Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchies
    -------------------------------------
    Total cost: $47.97

Thank you, have a nice day!
```

**HERE IS MY CODE**

```
print("Welcome to Dino's International Doughnut Shoppe!")
name = input("Please enter your name to begin: ")


choice = 0
while choice not in [1,2,3,4]:
    print("Please enter a valid choice from 1-4.")
    print("Please select a doughnut from the following menu: ")
    print("1. Chocolate-dipped Maple Puff ($3.50 each)")
    print("2. Strawberry Twizzler ($2.25 each)")
    print("3. Vanilla Chai Strudel ($4.05 each)")
    print("4. Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie ($1.99)")
    print("5. No more doughnuts.")
    choice = int(input(">"))


if choice == 1:
    chocolate = int(input("How many chocolate-dipped Maple Puff(s) would you like to purchase? "))
elif choice == 2:
    strawberry = int(input("How many Strawberry Twizzler(s) would you like to purchase? "))
elif choice == 3:
    vanilla = int(input("How many Vanilla Chai Strudel(s) would you like to purchase? "))
elif choice == 4:
    honey = int(input("How many Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie(s) would you like to purchase? "))

print(f"{name}, Here is your receipt: ")

if choice == 1:
    print("==========================================")
    print(f"{chocolate} Chocolate Dipped Maple Puffs")
    print("==========================================")
    print(f"Total Cost: ${chocolate*3.50:.2f}")
elif choice == 2:
    print("==========================================")
    print(f"{strawberry} Strawberry Twizzlers")
    print("==========================================")
    print(f"Total Cost: ${strawberry*2.25:.2f}")
elif choice == 3:
    print("==========================================")
    print(f"{vanilla} Vanilla Chai Strudels")
    print("==========================================")
    print(f"Total Cost: ${vanilla*4.05:.2f}")
elif choice == 4:
    print("==========================================")
    print(f"{honey} Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchies")
    print("==========================================")
    print(f"Total Cost: ${honey*1.99:.2f}")

print("Thank you for shopping at Dino's International Doughnut Shoppe! Please come again!")
```

Comment: You need another `while`-loop around the whole code.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating? I'm still new to python and I'm a bit confused...

Comment: If you want to repeat the whole code multiple times, the code should be included in another (outer) `while`-loop. If it should repeat endlessly, the condition of the loop can be simply `True`.

Comment: What I mean is that I want it so when the user selects a choice, the menu would repeat itself

Comment: To repeat something, like the code to show and handle the menu, you need a loop. A `while`-loop is here appropriate.

Comment: I added a while loop in the first line, its not repeating the menu, it just stops.

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong. Show the code (or just follow the structure shown by @gboffi).

Comment: Noah, my answer notwithstanding I have another suggestion for you:  don't use `5` as an exit code, use `0` instead... Why?  because using `0` you leave free your Shoppe to introduce another type of doughnut w/o changing the program.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I tried making an infinite loop for the menu that displays the doughnuts(works by doing x = 0 while x ==0: at the top of the menu choices), but how would I make it so when a user inputs "5" the loop would stop and continue to calculate the amount? (code at bottom)

Comment: @NoahSantos Noah, w.r.t. [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52692931/how-to-repeat-program-after-user-inputs-a-choice/52693162#comment92313772_52692931) of yours, i have addressed _exactly_ this issue (exiting the loop) in [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52693162/2749397).  If there is anything unclear, please make a comment below the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a homework problem, I don't want to give the code.
But I will say, you should consider putting all of your code in the while loop and change its terminating condition to 5. (ie, quit when "choice==5")
Then you can handle the logic of selections and invalid selections within the loop, say in a series of if-else.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest this code skeleton?

```
...
while True:   # i.e., loop  F O R E V E R
   reply = present_menu()
   if not (1 <= reply <= 5) :
       show_error_message()
       continue # i.e., abort this cycle and start a new loop cycle
   if reply == 5:
       recapitulation()
       break # i.e., exit the forever loop
   how_many = ask_how_many(reply)
   update_purchases(reply, how_many)
...
```

What really matters are the following ideas

- an infinite loop
- if the answer is unsatisfactory, abort and start a new iteration (i.e., presenting again the menu) using the `continue` statement
- if the user chooses to stop interaction, definitively exit the loop using the `break` statement.

You could put all  your code inside the loop according to these principles, or you can follow my suggestion and *abstract* repetitive pieces of code into auxiliary functions.

Comment: In many cases abstraction matters even if the code is not repeated because the names we choose for our functions are, or at least we hope so, more apt to tell the story than many lines of complicated code structures...